# Does R6RS improve the hygiene of Scheme macros?

Tags: scheme, lisp

The hygiene of Scheme macros as of R5RS was not fully understood (no clear definition of what it meant to be hygienic and whether those properties actually applied to Scheme macros [Oleg Kiselyov, Dirty Macros, 2002](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/Dirty-Macros.pdf))

Has R6RS improved the situation since then?

Comment: This is a fair question.  The answer depends on whether Oleg's `defile` and `let-leaky-syntax` still works in R6RS.  I'll speculate that they will, but I haven't tested it.  IMO this breaking of hygiene is only a theoretical concern and not a practical reason to doubt the hygiene of common macros, unless you're working against an actively malicious programmer.

Comment: Actually, your question as worded seems to be purely social/technical.  With regard to the quoted text, R6RS has itself had no effect on the issues raised by Oleg.  It has not revised the definition of hygiene.  Other work has surely changed the theoretical perspective on macros, some of it potentially generated by the R6RS process, but R6RS itself simply specified `syntax-case` which does allow for breaking hygiene, but does not attempt to resist tricks of the sort Oleg uses in this paper.

Comment: For what it's worth, R7RS uses the same `syntax-rules` system as R5RS, with minor improvements not related to hygiene. So there have not been any improvements to hygiene on that front...